# String behaviour during ordering data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In my application I download some data from website providing landscape informations like population, landscape area and few more.

After parsing html code, data are stored in list of objects

```
public class Landscape
{
    public int Population { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
}

public List<Landscape> data;
```

No problem with that. Follows filling dataGrid and that's purpose of my application. Now, where is the problem? Area info on the website is in semi-numeric, semi-string format. For example: *10 000 km2*.

I have possibility to choose whether to trim *km2* suffix and store data as int, or do nothing about it and store data as string. **Since I want have data in dataGrid in original format**, I decided not to trim.

Finally, is there a **way to order rows** (by size of area) **as int although it is string** type?

Comment: Are you sure you want to store the area as a string? I'd use a `Decimal` in a standard unit and only convert to string for display purposes.

Comment: I am not sure hence I am posting my current solution and awaiting experienced to advise me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linq to sort by the translated value but don't think this will be fast.

```
public class Landscape
{
    public int Population { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }

    public int TrimAndConvert()
    {
        /* Your Code to trim and convert to int */
    }
}


data.OrderBy(landscape => landscape.Area.TrimAndConvert());
```

I think a better way would be to save the Area as a number and add the trimmed part just for output.

```
public class Landscape
{
    public int Population { get; set; }
    public int AreaValue { get; set; }
    public string AreaUnit { get; set; }

    public string Area 
    {
        get 
        {
            return AreaValue.ToString() + AreaUnit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought this way, but I would rather solution where is no need of additional button for ordering data in dataGrid. If there is no way how to solve it just by clicking header in dataGrid, then your solution would be just fine. (Except there is no need of AreaUnit variable because I know trimmed part so I can only attach it as a string)

Comment: The AreaUnit property was just in case you would have different units (but that would of course make the sorting useless). You could implement `public int TrimAndConvert` as a property and have the DataGrid sort by it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement an IComparer and pass and instance of it to the List.Sort() method/overload that takes an IComparer.

This should get you started:

[`List<T>.Sort` Method (`IComparer<T>`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx)

Comment: Is it possible implement this IComparer in way I can attach it to dataGrid? In dataGrid you order rows just by clicking header, I think dataGrid has its own ICompare method I can't affect.